# CXF WS-SecureConversation disableCNCheck

Tags: cxf

I'm using Apache CXF 3.1.10 to talk to a Microsoft server running with WS-SecureConversation. The test server has a self-signed certificate and I have been unable to make a request. It fails every time with an invalid certificate. I have been unable to find a way to disable the check.

From what I have learned, WS-SecureConversation makes multiple calls. First it establishes a connection using the current client. Then it encrypts the message and makes a second call using STSClient, and that is the call that fails.

From all research I have done, the way to disable the certificate check is like this:

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

TLSClientParameters tlsParams = httpConduit.getTlsClientParameters();
if (tlsParams == null) {
    tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
}
tlsParams.setDisableCNCheck(true);
httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);
```

How do I make the TLS parameters apply to STSClient? Just an FYI that I am not able to use Spring so any suggestions I have found related to Spring config are not available to me.

```
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking <svc>: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1385)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1369)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:653)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.AbstractSTSClient.issue(AbstractSTSClient.java:861)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.SecureConversationOutInterceptor.issueToken(SecureConversationOutInterceptor.java:198)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.SecureConversationOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SecureConversationOutInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.SecureConversationOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SecureConversationOutInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:257)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1328)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1288)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:288)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1341)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: Is it possible to tell CXF to use a keystore for the certificate? That is another alternative, but importing it into the JVM didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I added an easy way to set the TLSClientParameters object on the STSClient directly, but it won't be available until the next set of releases:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-7665

It's a bit messy, but your only other alternative is to create the STSClient directly, and call "getClient" on it and to set the TLSClientParameters object on the associated HTTPConduit, e.g.:

STSClient stsClient = new STSClient(clientBus);
((HTTPConduit)stsClient.getClient().getConduit()).setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);

((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("security.sts.client", stsClient);

It may be though that the STSClient will not be configured properly by doing this, in which case you will have to look at how the default STSClient is configured, and see if you can set the appropriate values on it:

https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/982e4de7bd30563cde2582df702fa2994e52765f/rt/ws/security/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/ws/security/policy/interceptors/SecureConversationOutInterceptor.java#L189